# Unable to open the PayUMoney screen for card detail

Tags: android, payumoney

I am getting the resultCode = Result_Canceled in onActivityResult() method. How can I come to know the reason of that.

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PayUmoneyFlowManager.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        TransactionResponse transactionResponse = data.getParcelableExtra(PayUmoneyFlowManager.INTENT_EXTRA_TRANSACTION_RESPONSE);
        ResultModel resultModel = data.getParcelableExtra(PayUmoneyFlowManager.ARG_RESULT);

        if (transactionResponse != null && transactionResponse.getPayuResponse() != null) {
            Log.e("TAG", "tran "+payuResponse+"---"+ merchantResponse);
        } else if (requestCode == PayUmoneyFlowManager.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Cancelled ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
D/hash: cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e D/param :: key - J8H4uLWX , merchantId - 6780016, D/param :: txnid - txt12346 , amount - 1000 , surl - payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php , furl - payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php , productInfo - Subscription for paid data , email - renny@gmail.com , firstName - Renny , phone - 9643999108 , udf1 - udf2 - –
```

Comment: Please provide output logs

Comment: I am getting null in data field in onActivityResult() method